# google rich snippets (reviews) showing completely incorrectly?

Tags: seo, rich-snippets, google-rich-snippets

I'm working on rich snippet review data for a website; there aren't any reviews rich snippets showing on a page that google links to, but the SERP result shows a 5 star rating with 800 ratings?

here's the search to see the rating: [artworx](https://www.google.com/?gws_rd=ssl#q=bizyhood%20artworx)

and here's the page google links to: [artworx bizyhood page](https://www.bizyhood.com/business/details/overview/artworx-events-marlboro-nj-07746/20ce24bd-bb71-4315-a545-ee604c455946/)

Anyone have any ideas why a review count of 800+ is showing with a 5 star rating when the rating is not present on the destination URL?

Comment: view the source code of the cache page, you have ratings there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [version of your page which Google has cached](http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:https://www.bizyhood.com/business/details/overview/artworx-events-marlboro-nj-07746/20ce24bd-bb71-4315-a545-ee604c455946/&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&gws_rd=cr&ei=VGlQVYbFK8W1sQGd44C4CA) (from 2015-03-23) contains an `AggregateRating`:

```html
<div class="score high clearfix" itemprop="aggregateRating" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/AggregateRating">          
  <meta itemprop="ratingCount" content="804" />
  <meta itemprop="worstRating" content="33" />
  <meta itemprop="bestRating" content="100" />
  <span id="business-score" itemprop="ratingValue">100</span>
  <h6>Customer Rating</h6>
  <small>View customer feedback</small>
</div>
```

The next time the Googlebot crawls this page and updates its cache, Google Search will likely no longer show this Rich Snippet.

Comment: Interesting this makes sense. Thanks for the answer Unor!